# How to print a list of symbols exported from a dynamic library

Tags: macos, dylib

So I've been trying to get dynamic libraries to work in my XCode project under Mac OS X. So far no joy.

I am able to load the dylib file, but when I call dlsym to get the function pointer, it returns 0 and dlerror says symbol not found.

So I am wondering if there is a simple way to list the symbols that are exported from a dylib file. Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

man 1 nm

https://web.archive.org/web/20160316222941/https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nm.1.html

For example:

```
nm -gU /usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.12.16/lib/cairo/libcairo-trace.0.dylib
```

Comment: Under OS X Leopard (10.5, yeah, I know...) you should use `nm -gu` , i.e. the `-u` option is lowercase.

Comment: man 1 nm is self-contained and will continue working when command line changes :p

Comment: @MK. `man 1 nm` lists a lot of things one can do with nm.  Again, it's an external resource one can read through to discover a solution, but not a solution itself to the requested _“a simple way to list the symbols that are exported from a dylib file”_.  “`nm -gU ….dylib`” is, however.

Comment: How about for macOS frameworks:`/System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa`

Answer (score 68):

Use [otool](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/otool/):

```
otool -TV your.dylib
```

OR

```
nm -g your.dylib
```

Comment: On new macOS, otool -T will show `otool: -T functionality obsolete`
use objdump -t

Comment: While it's true that `otool -T` reports `functionality obsolete` in newer OS X, it's also true that (for dynamic libraries) `objdump -t` will report `The file was not recognized as a valid object file.`

Answer (score 16):

Use `nm -a your.dylib`

It will print all the symbols including globals

Answer (score 0):

Use Mach-OView for viewing all the Symbols in dylib

https://sourceforge.net/projects/machoview/

Comment: I was excited to have learned of this GUI but it crashed for me after I loaded a dylib. I'm using macOS Mojave.

Comment: @chrisdembia You might have more luck with the active-ish GitHub fork at https://github.com/gdbinit/MachOView. I believe https://github.com/fangshufeng/MachOView is a binary of an older version of that fork, use at your own risk.