# dylib or executable export list

Tags: ios, macos, dynamic, dylib, dlopen

I am writing a plugins subsystem and one of the ideas is to iterate through a dylib (or at least current global scope) exported functions. I know there are other ways, just really want to give this one a try.

What I am wondering, is there a way to get a list of functions exported by a dylib or available in global scope through OS X and iOS API?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One of the ideas for what?

Comment: @trojanfoe what I need is to get the list of exports for dylib or for global scope. Idea for what? A plugins subsystem I want to try to implement. Need the names to make configuration maintainable through configs.

Comment: Normally plugins define a set of known functions that the loading binary will call; isn't that how you want your plugin system to work?

Comment: No, I want to enumerate the list of exported stuff.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print a list of symbols exported from a dynamic library on OSX (dylib)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506121/how-to-print-a-list-of-symbols-exported-from-a-dynamic-library-on-osx-dylib)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Need to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a command 'nm' for getting an information from a dynamic library.
See additionally system manual for this command on Mac.

Comment: Sorry, too slow. Need something to get access to in-memory table.

Comment: Nothing standard allows this. There are nonstandard extensions, it's particularly _un_likely that they exist on ios. Best to plan on having one well-known exported function that catalogs the others.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do that from code, you could use this method.

```
std::vector<std::string> load_mach_o(std::string file_name)
{
  /*
  Parse the Mach-O structure to find all the exported symbols
  Mach-O structure:
   mach_header_64
   cmd
   ...
   cmd
   data
   ...
   data
  */
  std::vector<std::string> methods; 
  off_t offset = sizeof(struct mach_header_64);
  BYTE * bytes = load_bytes(file_name.c_str());
  if (bytes == NULL)
  {
    return methods;
  }

  struct mach_header_64 *header = (struct mach_header_64 *)bytes;
  //Get the load commands
  struct load_command *cmd = (struct load_command *)(bytes + offset);

  for (uint32_t i = 0U; i < header->ncmds; i++)
  {
    if (cmd->cmd == LC_SYMTAB)
    {
      struct symtab_command * symtab = (struct symtab_command *)cmd;
      off_t string_start = 0;
      const char* strings = (const char *)(bytes + symtab->stroff + 1);
      for (uint32_t i = 0 ; i < symtab->strsize ; i++)
      {
        if (strings[i] == '\0')
        {
        i++;
        size_t size = sizeof(char) * (i - string_start);
        if (size == 1)
        {
          string_start = i+1;
          continue;
        }
        methods.push_back(std::string((const char *)(strings + string_start)));
        string_start = i+1;
        }
      }
    }
    offset += cmd->cmdsize;
    //load next command
    cmd = (struct load_command *)(bytes + offset);
  }
  free(bytes);
  return methods;
}
```

This function read the file and parses the structure till mach-O strings section, then, parses each string and store it in a vector containing all the exposed functions.

Best regards.