# How to find objective-c methods at runtime for any Application on Mac?

Tags: macos, reverse-engineering, ida, dtrace, hopper

For ex- You have TextEdit Application, when you save the file , I want to know which objective-c methods get called. I have headers file of Textedit using class-dump.

Is there any is way to know which of these methods (which we output from class-dump) gets called at runtime?

is there any way to do it with dtrace??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Objective-C methods translate directly to user-space function calls, you should be able to use [the DTrace pid provider](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5488/gcgmc/index.html):

> **The `pid` Provider**
>
> The `pid` provider **enables you to trace any instruction in a
>   process**. Unlike most other providers, `pid` probes are created on
>   demand, based on the probe descriptions found in your D programs.
>
> **User Function Boundary Tracing**
>
> The simplest mode of operation for the `pid` provider is as the user
>   space analogue to the `fbt` provider. The following example program
>   traces all function entries and returns that are made from a single
>   function. The `$1` macro variable expands to the first operand on the
>   command line. This macro variable is the process ID for the process to
>   trace. The `$2` macro variable expands to the second operand on the
>   command line. This macro variable is the name of the function that all
>   function calls are traced from.
>
> **Example 4–3 `userfunc.d`: Trace User Function Entry and Return**
>
> ```
> pid$1::$2:entry
> {
>   self->trace = 1;
> }
>
> pid$1::$2:return
> /self->trace/
> {
>   self->trace = 0;
> }
>
> pid$1:::entry,
> pid$1:::return
> /self->trace/
> {
> }
> ```
>
> This script produces output that is similar to the following example:
>
> ```
> # ./userfunc.d 15032 execute
> dtrace: script './userfunc.d' matched 11594 probes
>   0  -> execute                               
>   0    -> execute                             
>   0      -> Dfix                              
>   0      <- Dfix                              
>   0      -> s_strsave                         
>   0        -> malloc                          
>   0        <- malloc                          
>   0      <- s_strsave                         
>   0      -> set                               
>   0        -> malloc                          
>   0        <- malloc                          
>   0      <- set                               
>   0      -> set1                              
>   0        -> tglob                           
>   0        <- tglob                           
>   0      <- set1                              
>   0      -> setq                              
>   0        -> s_strcmp                        
>   0        <- s_strcmp                        
> ...
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your information. But I need more. I have class-dump of TextEdit. In that I want to find out whether - (BOOL)validateMenuItem:(id)arg1; of class Document is executed or not. So I used your script and executed with dtrace -s userfunc.d 1102 *validateMenuItem* ... It says probe description does not match. What to do??

Comment: @hrishikeshchaudhari The function name might not be exactly `validateMenuItem`. It's likely [mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). I'm not familiar with OS X to say what utilities are available to find actual mangled function names in binaries.  `strings -a /bin/file | grep -i validateMenuItem` *might* work.  This might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506121/how-to-print-a-list-of-symbols-exported-from-a-dynamic-library  Shortening the DTrace script to something like `pid$1:::entry {}` might emit *all* function calls the process makes. I can't test that right now.

Comment: You are probably right, The functions are mangled. There is only way now to do it by reverse engineering or trial and error. I really wonder how people do swizzling. Reverse engineering probably will take days to find exact function to do swizzling.

Comment: @ Andrew Henle any comments on reverse engineering done in MAC OSX and how to do it?? I guess IDA and dtrace are some of the tools used for reverse engineering on mac.